# privilege and reputation mismatch

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I  am quite an active user on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Today when I logged in, I got below notification of earning new privilege. But I can not see my reputation enough to get this privilege.(111/125). Also did not receive any -ve response on any of my Q&A.

Are my reputations and privileges not in sync.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps an answer you accepted was deleted. Go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5146424/mk08?tab=reputation), scroll down and check the show removed posts checkbox at the bottom. Can you see a deleted accept (-15) in the list now?

Comment: @Robert Longson : Thanks for suggesting this check. But no there is no -15 on it. :(

Comment: Exactly same as in the dupe: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33228467/timeline), your answer was accepted for 3 seconds, which was enough for the privilege check to kick in, and send you the notification.

Comment: Oh got it. Thanks for sharing the question.